# Speeding up the calculation of integrations of a squared(powered) term using orthogonality(orthogonalities) of trigonometric functions

Tags: integration, trigonometry, fourier-analysis, systems-of-equations, orthogonality

$$  \int_{-\pi }^{\pi } \left\{ 1+ \cos^{}\left(t\right) -2 \cos^{}\left(2t\right) + 3 \cos^{}\left(3t\right) -4 \sin^{}\left(4t\right) + 5 \sin^{}\left(5t\right)  \right\} ^{2}  \,dx   $$

Of course this term can be calculated developing  $~ \left\{ 1+ \cos^{}\left(t\right) -2 \cos^{}\left(2t\right) + 3 \cos^{}\left(3t\right) -4 \sin^{}\left(4t\right) + 5 \sin^{}\left(5t\right)  \right\} ^{2} ~$  and using orthogonalities of trigonometric functions.

But isn't there some more efficient or faster way(s) to find out the value of the integrations? , like using some convenient formula(s).

At this rate, I have to handle 36 terms.

Comment: You only have to handle 6 terms in view of orthogonality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using orthogonalities of trigonometric functions is indeed the fastest way to  evaluate the integral. For this reason, all the $6\cdot 5=30$ integrals of double products are zero. Moreover, for the remaining $6$ integrals of squares, recall that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}1 \,dt=2\pi$ and for any integer $n\not=0$,
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos^{2}\left(nt\right)\,dt=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin^{2}\left(nt\right)\,dt=\pi.$$
It follows that the integral is equal to:
$$(2+1^2+(-2)^2+3^2+(-4)^2+5^2)\pi=57\pi$$